# How do I conditionally, automatically, add information to git commits comments?

Tags: git, github, hook

I'm looking to automatically add information to certain git commit comments.

For example, I can run a script in the pre-commit phase and detect whether there are any changes to some sort of application configuration templates, and add a comment to the git commit to that effect (say, something like "WARNING! This commit changes configuration templates, you may need to do a full rebuild to get the changes")

Does git provide this through an existing tool/extension/api call?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `prepare-commit-msg` hook that can be used to generate an initial commit message before opening an editor:

> **prepare-commit-msg**
>        This hook is invoked by git commit right after preparing the default log message, and before the editor is started.

There is a `commit-msg` hook that can be used to modify the commit message:

> **commit-msg**
>          This hook is invoked by git commit, and can be bypassed with --no-verify option. It takes a single parameter, the name of the file that holds the
>          proposed commit log message. Exiting with non-zero status causes the git commit to abort.

Either of one of these could be used to implement the behavior you're looking for.  You could implement your logic in either one of these, depending on whether you wanted the message available by default (but amendable to editing) or unilaterally set regardless of the commit message provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

#### Git notes

Git has a build in feature called notes.
simple add `git notes` to the commit and you can add notes to each commit. The notes is not part of teh commit hash so you can change it when ever you want.

ex:

```
git notes add -m 'This i snotes to a given commit' <SHA-1>
```

[image]